# Swagger UI not redirecting to /swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm using `springdoc-openapi-ui` 1.6.4 and springboot 2.7.5.

I try to access `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html`, I expect the URL will redirecting to `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config`
but it always redircting to `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html`

I also try to access `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html`, It will not redirecting to `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config`.

Can any one help me to redirect the URL to `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upgrade `springdoc-openapi-ui` to 1.6.6 resolved my issue.

referer :
[Springdoc Swagger UI not using swagger-config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71721477/springdoc-swagger-ui-not-using-swagger-config)